# How to list three part-time, concurrent jobs on resume?

Tags: resume

I currently work three part-time, concurrent jobs to maintain a full-time salary. I usually go for listing one of them as the current job on my resume but I feel like my responsibilities in this part-time gig doesn't give companies the full picture.

I tried to list the three concurrent jobs but they look awkward on my resume. Since I left my job 9 months ago, I took the three jobs at different periods so I'm afraid it might give the wrong impression that I'm jumping between jobs or outright confuse them.

**What's the best way to format my three part-time, concurrent jobs on my resume?**

Comment: Related, not quite duplicate: [How to list concurrent jobs on a CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17210/how-to-list-concurrent-jobs-on-a-cv)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given the nature of resume screening software, I would avoid any nifty grouping or hierarchical organization of the jobs because that would likely confuse the software and you'd get tossed without anyone seeing you.

Just go ahead and list them, with the end date being "Present".

> **Company 1, Job Title (Part-time)**
>   January 2018 - Present. *Explanation of job responsibilities and accomplishments...*
>
> **Company 2, Job Title (Part-time)**
>   March 2018 - Present. *Explanation of job responsibilities and accomplishments...*
>
> **Company 3, Job Title (Part-time)**
>   May 2018 - Present. *Explanation of job responsibilities and accomplishments...*

*(Your formatting may be different, but you get the idea...)*

You can address the fact that you're currently working all three at the same time in your **cover letter**, and/or when they ask you about it after having reviewed your resume.

Comment: Yep, this is what I would expect to see as a hiring manager.